# slow table comparison

Tags: php, mysql

I have written down this code to compare two tables and find out the difference but it is very slow, normally I have to compare 4k rows. It actually takes 3 min to complete.

```
$query = $pdo->query("select * from tab1 order by date_time ASC");
$calls = array();
foreach($query as $row){
    //check the differences
    $from = substr($row['from'],4,15); //remove prefix
    $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'
               , strtotime('-2 minute',strtotime($row['date_time']))); 
               //decrease of 2 min the time to match all time differences
    $duration = $pdo->query(
       "select duration
        , abs(duration - ".$row['duration'].") as duration_diff
        , price from tab2 
        where date_time between '".$date_time."' and '".$row['date_time']."' 
        and from like '%".$row['from']."' 
        and duration >0 
        order by duration_diff"
      )->fetch();

    //highlight the differences
    if ($row['duration'] > $duration['duration'] ):
        $color = "#ff0000";
    elseif ($row['duration'] < $duration['duration'] ):
        $color = "#ff9900";
    else:
        $color = "#fff";
    endif;
    $calls[] = array(
       "date_time" => $row['date_time'], 
       "from" => $row['from'], 
       "to" => $row['to'], 
       "duration_tab1" => $row['duration'], 
       "duration_tab2" => $duration['duration'], 
       "price_tab1" => $row['price'], 
       "price_tab2" => substr($duration['price'],0,6), 
       "color" => $color);
  }
```

All the fields in table structure are varchar, there are no indexes.
Which indexes on which fields have to be added to increase the performance?

Comment: Step 1: Remove `$from = substr($row['from'],4,15);` as `$from` never gets used.

Comment: I don't think you can speed up that code as you always need to talk back to MySQL every single row.

Comment: `and from like`:  This code should not work; it should generate a syntax error because `from` is a reserved word.

Comment: @user1739269, show structure(schema) for `tab1` and `tab2` tables

Answer (score 1):

There is N+1 Mysql Query in your code.

Since 4k rows are not too much, I suggest that you can fetch the whole table1 and table2. And do the comparison in PHP code. It should be faster.

```
$query = $pdo->query("select * from tab1 order by date_time ASC");
$query1 = $pdo->query("select * from tab2 order by date_time ASC");
....
```

Comment: Use appropriate indexes on your SQL tables will help also...  (even querying 'only' 4000 rows).

Comment: wich type of indexes have to use and on wich fields? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pulling a value into php land from a query in a loop then injecting that value into another query executed in a loop is an anti-pattern.

Your database is not normalized - which is causing a lot of complications for you.

Your database is *very* loosely coupled - which is compounding the complexity.

You've not provided any details of the table structure nor the indexes.

Your problem statement does not address the relative cardinality of the datasets - e.g. what happens if there are no matching rows in tab2.

If you fixed your schema, then it would be trivial to do the join in the database. As it stands, I am extremely dubious as to whether your code will produce reproducible results. However the same results could be obtained by using a function to pull the relevant records out of table 2, something like....

```
 CREATE FUNCTION tab2data(pfrom VARCHAR
 , pdate_time DATETIME
 , pduration FLOAT)
 RETURNS VARCHAR
 BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(200);

    SELECT CONCAT(tab2.duration, '#',
         ABS(tab2.duration-pduration), '#',
         tab2.date_time, '#',
         tab2.price, '#',
         tab2.`from`, '#',
         tab2.`to`, '#')
    INTO result
    FROM tab2
    WHERE `from` LIKE CONCAT('%',pfrom)
    AND date_time BETWEEN pdate_time AND pdate_time + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    AND duration>0
    ORDER BY ABS(tab2.duration-pduration)
    LIMIT 0,1;

    return result;
  END;
```

Comment: both tables don't have indexes all the fields are varchar.

Comment: OMG - you're never going to get this to work at any speed.