# How to reduce the loading time of data mysql, codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have like 400 plus records to retrieve from this method and it almost takes 2 minutes to load the page. So please help me how to reduce the loading time of this method.

```
function teacher_attendance_selector()

    {

        $data['year']       = $this->input->post('year');
        $data['timestamp']  =strtotime($this->input->post('timestamp'));
        $query = $this->db->get_where('teacher_attendance' ,array(
                  'teacher_id'=>$data['teacher_id'],
             'year'=>$data['year'],

        ));



        if($query->num_rows() < 1) {
            $teachers = $this->db->get_where('teacher' , array(

            ))->result_array();

            foreach($teachers as $row) {
                $attn_data['year']       = $data['year'];
                $attn_data['timestamp']  = $data['timestamp'];
                $attn_data['teacher_id'] = $row['teacher_id'];

                $this->db->insert('teacher_attendance' , $attn_data);  
            }

        }
  redirect(base_url().'index.php?admin/manage_teacher_attendance_view/'.$data['timestamp'],'refresh');
        }
```

Comment: Avoid query in loop will help alot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to speed up this php/mysql code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034815/how-to-speed-up-this-php-mysql-code)

Comment: without query loop i cant insert in to the teacher_attendance table..it has to be happen at this point

Comment: this is not pure php .this is codeigniter

Comment: everyone is aware that this is codeignitor but what @walf says is still very valid. INSERT SELECT is the way forward. Now I myself am not familiar how to do INSERT SELECT in code ignitor or I would provide you with an answer but i am sure it's there in the docs

Comment: In your first query, `$data['teacher_id']` seems to come from nowhere. Then you add an attendance record for *every* teacher in the database. It doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks @Wolf i am going to check on that

Comment: you can use indexing for optimise execution time of mysql query make `teacher` column as index column.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is taking a huge time.
Follow the below suggested way, you can store all data in one array and then you can use only one query to insert all the records stored in that array.

see below code you will get more ideas how to achieve performance.

```html
function teacher_attendance_selector()

    {

        $data['year']       = $this->input->post('year');
        $data['timestamp']  =strtotime($this->input->post('timestamp'));
        $query = $this->db->get_where('teacher_attendance' ,array(
                  'teacher_id'=>$data['teacher_id'],
             'year'=>$data['year'],

        ));



        if($query->num_rows() < 1) {
            $teachers = $this->db->get_where('teacher' , array())->result_array();

            $arr_batchinsert = array();

            foreach($teachers as $row) {
                $attn_data['year']       = $data['year'];
                $attn_data['timestamp']  = $data['timestamp'];
                $attn_data['teacher_id'] = $row['teacher_id'];
                
                // PREPARE ARRAY FOR BATCH INSERT
                $arr_batchinsert = $attn_data;
            }

            // insert here using insert_batch
            $this->db->insert_batch('teacher_attendance', $arr_batchinsert ); 


        }
  redirect(base_url().'index.php?admin/manage_teacher_attendance_view/'.$data['timestamp'],'refresh');
        }
```

Comment: i tried with like 20 data set with this method but its not even inserting to the database nor giving an error